# Best Practice to Receive Service Updates: Callbacks or Broadcasts?

Tags: android

If i have a simple service, for example a service that checks for a valid internet connection by calling a service and receiving a response code and then updating the UI (i.e. a toolbar icon in the activity) based on the response whenever available (the UI won't wait for the response)

which practice is better: implementing a callback function which is called by the service and implemented by the activity or using the local broadcast manager

Comment: Use broadcast receivers, since it's more convenient way to receive callbacks from service. But background services are deprecated right now, so if you're gonna use binded service, you can check state via binder. Or even better, use WorkManager for periodic work

Comment: thanks for the tip about WorkManager!

Comment: I prefer BroadcastReceiver approach. But use a LocalBroadcastReceiver instead